# How to set mono channel to two channels in video sequence rendering?

Tags: rendering, edit-mode, audio

The source video has mono audio microphone recording on the left side only.

How do I setup Blender for rendering audio to two channels (copy left to right)?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate the media that comes in with source clip, Blender will think that it is stereo. Hard pan 1 strip to the left, then hard pan the other strip to the right. If you want to keep the output split then use Audio mixdown in the project properties panel next to the animation render button.